# If $f : D(0;1) \setminus \{ 0 \}$ holomorphic such that $f(1/n) = 0$ then either $f=0$ or $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series, singularity

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D(0; 1)\setminus\{0\}$ with the property that $f(1/n) = 0$ for every positive integer $n$. Show that $f$ is either identically zero, or that $f$ has an
>   essential singularity at $0$. Give an example of the latter.

I'm thinking I need to use the Laurent expansion of the function to show the singularity is essential, but I'm unsure of how to do that since I don't know the function. I'm confused about how to show it could be identically zero as well. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You don't show it, you assume it is not to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ does not have an essential singularity at $0$ then it has either a pole or  a removable singularity. If it is a removable singularity then defining it to be $0$ at $0$ gives an analytic function in the open unit disk whose zeros have a limit point, so $f \equiv 0$. If it has  a pole then necessarily $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $ z \to 0$ but this is false because $f(\frac 1 n)=0$ for all $n$. An example where $f$ has an essential singularity is $f(z)=\sin (\frac {\pi} z)$.

Comment: Also, why does f approach infinity as z approaches zero?

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: This is one of the characterizations of poles: if $f$ has a isolated singularity at $c$ then the singularity is a pole iff $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to c$. Both Rudin and Conway have a proof.

Comment: Would you mind linking a proof? I tried googling it but can't seem to find an answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Here is a simple proof: write $f(z)=g(z)+\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac {a_k} {(z-c)^{k}}$ with $a_N \neq 0$ (which means $f$ has a pole of order $N$ at $c$). Multiply by $(z-c)^{N}$ and take limit as $z \to c$. You get $\lim_{z\to c} |(z-c)^{N}f(z)| =|a_N|$. This implies $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to c$.

Comment: Thanks! one more clarification, f(1/n) = 0 for n greater than zero, so how can you compare f(z) approaching infinity to the function at 0 if it is not defined there?

Answer (score 0):

**Abridged proof.** If $f$ does not have an essential singularity at zero and is not the function zero, Laurent development at zero gives an analytic function $f_1$ on the disc and an integer $m \geq 0$ such that $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z^m} f_1(z),$ with $f_1(0) \neq 0.$ $f_1$ being analytic, cannot have cluster values for its set of zeroes, violating the hypothesis. Q.E.D.